# Angular 2 and MySQL concepts

Tags: mysql, angular

Are there recommended concepts how to access MySQL from an Angular 2 application?

I'm new to Angular and Typescript. I found and installed the `node-mysql` package. I would like to SELECT some datasets for computational analysis and some graphical representation (perhaps with d3).

My own concept would be to implement a singleton service encapsulating the connection and SQL calls.

But perhaps I am thinking too old school here? Perhaps there should be a different approach?

On the practical side, I'm uncertain how to import the `node-mysql` package in Angular2 / Typescript - by importing the package at the top?

If someone could point me to an example, I'd be glad to learn.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Communication directly from Angular to Mysql is bad practice (in most cases). Angular runs client side and exposing mysql to it allows for anybody to run arbitrary SQL statements.

The solution is to create an intermidate server. It could run nodejs, to which you can then import node-mysql. The nodejs server could expose a REST api which your angular 2 application consumes.

Comment: You wouldn't create a backend for a database viewer application, would you?

Comment: @Dragas That really depends on what is meant by database viewer. If it is a database management UI then I would likely not, but for most cases I would not expose an SQL interface to end-users. Unless of course it is a database management tool.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Angular-Meteor](https://www.angular-meteor.com).
If you were in any framework other than Meteor, you'd need to start implementing a series of REST endpoints to connect the server to the client.But Meteor makes writing distributed client code as simple as talking to a local database.
More in this article: https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/3-way-data-binding