# Angular 2. Rendering template I have removed from templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, angular2-routing

Hi I am really new to angular 2.
Issue is I am implemented Routing which is working fine but then on New_Contact route I replaced templateUrl with template but it is still loading old html file for that route

OLD Component
new_contact.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector  :'new-contact',
  templateUrl  :'app/ts/html/new_contact_form.html'
})
```

CURRENT COMPONent

```
@Component({
  selector  :'new-contact',
  template  :'Blah'
})
```

But that route still rendering old templateUrl.

Main.ts file where route mentioned is

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { Component, provide } from 'angular2/core';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';
import { ContactDisplayComponent } from './contact_display.component';
import { NewContact } from './new_contact.component';
import { EditContact } from './edit_contact.component';



@Component({
  selector:'app-start',
  template:`
  <navbar></navbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives : [NavbarComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/',name:'Home',component:ContactDisplayComponent},
  {path:'/New_Contact',name:'New_Contact',component:NewContact},
  {path:'/Edit_Contact/:id',name:'Edit_Contact',component:EditContact}
])

export class Main{
}

bootstrap(Main,
  [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
  ]
);
```

Navbar Component where router link is placed

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';


@Component({
  selector  :'navbar',
  templateUrl:'/app/ts/html/navbar.html',
  styleUrls : ['../resources/navbar_support.css'],
  directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})


export class NavbarComponent
{}
```

***NAVBAR.HTML***

```
    <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-fixed navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                    <img src="../resources/phonebook_brand.png" class="img-responsive"/>
                </a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['New_Contact']">New</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the link to complete code, if any one of you can have a look just do npm install and npm start and we are good to go

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpuqg8lhtu4wb42/Routing%201%20test.rar?dl=0

I have also included underscore library using npm install for computaion

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+F5 in the browser to force reload? Maybe also restart the HTTP server you are using.

Comment: Are you sure you recompiled the typescript file :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in your `tsconfig.json` file preventing from compiling your TypeScript files. The path `/app/js` isn't correct in this file. See the error:

```
(...)
[0] error TS5033: Could not write file '/app/js/new_contact.component.js': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app'
[0] error TS5033: Could not write file '/app/js/new_contact.component.js.map': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app'
```

You should use the path `app/js` instead. Here is the udpate to do:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "app/js", // <--------------
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Your JS file remained the same since your update wasn't compiled and taken into account within your appliction in the browser...

Comment: Yes that was the issue.. where to find these error ... also I find error in browser console very difficult to understand ,,, how to find error like you do

Comment: In fact, you had an error in the console that started the `npm run start`... What is your error in the browser console?

Comment: working on my app and like to connect it to MySQL but not finding any tutorial for Angular2 and MySQL if you could point me in right direction         Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368897/angular-2-and-mysql-concepts?lq=1         and understood need a intermediate server but how to make it if any tutorial or explaining ...please provide one